# Cocos2D SpriteBatchNode vrs. SpriteFrameCache... I do not see any performance difference

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have tried using both ways...

1. adding the .png file on the cache with SpriteFrameCache..
2. adding .plist with spritebatchnode adding the correspoding .png file, I didnt see any performance difference.

In my test I keep adding and adding objects with the same image.. in this case a bullet... eventually the app crashed because it ran out of memory. Same thing happened to both situations with SpriteFrameCache and SpriteBatchNode they both dropped FPS to 30(when its supposed to be 60) and then just crashes...I understand the scenario is not real.And obviously its destiny its to crash if I just keep adding images without destroying objects that are no longer in use...but the question remains.

I saw the same performance issue, however I read that SpriteBatchNode makes only one draw call making it best performance practice. Has anyone tried and can confirm the performance difference and exactly how can you prove this performance difference in code and in the app?

Comment: Sorry to question your testing, but the performance boost is definite ... Make sure you are testing on a real iOS device, preferably iPhone 4 or older, and you're not adding the objects in a tight for loop, but instead, add 25 or so each second. [reference](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/09/cocos2d-spritebatch-performance-test/)

Comment: interesting... thanks will try on an older device... does it really make that huge difference the iPhone 4S that it does not feel the difference?

Comment: Actually, it should be fine testing on iPhone 4S, and you should see the difference. But now that I think about it, make sure you are animating stuff on the screen, too. Sometimes the screen FPS counter isn't precise.

Comment: enable displayStats and watch the number for draw calls. Batch node effect is greater when using sprites of different textures and larger sizes. There may not be much draw call overhead on tiny bullet sprites to begin with. It can be as low as 10% performance difference for single-texture, tiny, non-rotated, non-scaled sprites.

Comment: ps batch node and sprite frames are different concepts,perhaps you simply test two unrelated bits of code. Post your code.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D maybe you are right, but i dont get it... I've read on many places how they relate to each other in performance... and I have tried one way and another they both give the same solition.. but are different codings, so I am logically assuming that they are seperated by performance difference according to WHEN to use each method.

Comment: batching improves performance, sprite frames are just data the engine needs to render smaller bits of a texture atlas. It just so happens that texture atlases also help improve batching efficiency because you can draw more objects from the same texture

Comment: Thanks a lot... definitely the answers I needed to hear.

Comment: One thing i have in doubt still tho is this... SpriteFrameCache does it benefit in any way? because even if I dont use that Code [CCSpriteFrameCache addSpriteFramesWithFile:plist textureFilename:texture]... 

And I understood now 100% what is the Batchnode purpose, I saw a performance boost, from 14 draw calls to 9 drawcalls, and the render time call 0.0016 to 0.011... its not that huge, but its noticable